# Configure client caching when using OWIN static files

Tags: c#, caching, owin

This is my Startup.cs where I map my index page to the route '/app'.

```
...
using Microsoft.Owin.FileSystems;
using Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles;
using Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(conApi.Startup))]

namespace conApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ////Set static files
            ConfigureFiles(app);

            //Enable Cors
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        }

        public void ConfigureFiles(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Map("/app", spa =>
            {
                spa.Use((context, next) =>
                {
                    context.Request.Path = new PathString("/index.html");

                    return next();
                });

                spa.UseStaticFiles();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

It works like a charm but I don't know how to configure the client caching. I would like to know how to set the Expires header if that is possible when using OWIN static files?

**SOLUTION** 
Tratcher provided the link to the StaticFilesOptions class documentation etc which lead me to a solution. Added the StaticFilesOptions to the ConfigureFiles method like this:

```
public void ConfigureFiles(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var staticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
    {
        OnPrepareResponse = (StaticFileResponseContext) =>
        {
            StaticFileResponseContext.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control",new[] { "public", "max-age=1000" });
        }
    };

    app.Map("/app", spa =>
    {
        spa.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            context.Request.Path = new PathString("/index.html");

            return next();
        });

        spa.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a StaticFilesOptions to UseStaticFiles. On the options use the OnPrepareResponse event to customize your responses. See http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles/StaticFileOptions.cs